# pickle, dill - ImportError: No module named moduleA.moduleB.moduleC

Tags: python, oop, pickle, dill

I have a problem with `pickle.load()` from a file. Dump and load is done in `dill_read_write.py`:

**dill_read_write.py**

```
import os
import dill
from contact_geometry import ContactGeometry

def write_pickle(obj, filename):
    os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
    filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as output_:
        dill.dump(obj, output_)

def read_pickle(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as input_:
        return dill.load(input_)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    read_pickle("ground_.pkl")
```

Saving object `ContactGeometry` data to pickle file is done when the PyQt application (project) is running. Function `write()` is called in `moduleC.py`:

**moduleC.py**

```
from contact_geometry import ContactGeometry
from moduleA.moduleB import dill_read_write

class Foo(FooItem):
    def __init__(self,...):
        ...
    def createGeometry(self):
        contact_geometry_ = ContactGeometry()
        #   save object to pickle file
        dill_read_write.write_pickle(contact_geometry_, "object_data.pkl")
```

The object is saved and pickle file is created. But when I run only the file `dill_read_write.py` to read (load) object data from pickle file I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\projectName\moduleA\moduleB\dill_read_write.py", line 29, in <module>
read("ground_.pkl")
File "C:\projectName\moduleA\moduleB\dill_read_write.py", line 24, in read
return dill.load(input_)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dill-0.2.2-py2.7.egg\dill\dill.py", line 199, in load
obj = pik.load()
File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dill-0.2.2-py2.7.egg\dill\dill.py", line 278, in find_class
return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
File "C:\Python27\Lib\pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
__import__(module)
ImportError: No module named moduleA.moduleB.contact_geometry
```

I searched a bit and found that `dill` can perform better than `pickle` with classes but I am having problems to implement it. I've also found that I have to implement `__reduce__()` in class `ContactGeometry` in file `contact_geometry.py`.

**contact_geometry.py**

```
class ContactGeometry(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...    
    def __reduce__(self):
        return (self.__class__, (os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

But I am not sure what should return this method? How could I successfully load pickle file from the current situation?

Below is the project structure, if it is any help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an` __all__` in each of the `__init__`s?

Comment: Ex. `__all__ = ["foo.py","bar.py"]

Comment: At the moment no. If I understand your suggestion for example (see project tree structure figure), for `__init__.py` in package `moduleB` I should add: `__all__=[contac_geometry.py, moduleC.py, dill_read_write.py?]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a python file *from within* a package like that; it wouldn't find the toplevel package names. I'd propose any of the following:

1. Write a start script in at the top level (where the `main.py` is), that imports and runs the `read_write_dill` from `moduleA.moduleB`
2. Instead in the top level directory, where the `main` is, you can run
   that module with `python -m moduleA.moduleB.dill_read_write`.
3. Or, my preferred alternative, write a [`setup.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) for your project and write a [script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) for that utility.

Comment: @Antii Haapala I went for your 1. suggestion and it worked! Thanks. Saved a lot of time. I'll try to learn something new about your other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the `dill` author.  It's hard to tell how you are running the code, but it looks like the issue is that one way you are running the code and the module name as in @Antti Haapala's answer.  His suggestions are also good ones to follow.

I'll add this… You need to make sure that (1) `moduleA.moduleB.contact_geometry` is on the `PYTHONPATH`, and (2) you are not dumping the module as `__main__.moduleB.contact_geometry` and trying to load it as `moduleA.moduleB.contact_geometry` -- `dill` treats `__main__` as if it were a module (for the most part).

You shouldn't need to add `__reduce__` methods to your classes, however.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have not tried it yet, as I used 1. suggestion of @Antti Haapala's answer and it worked. I will remove `__reduce__` as you suggested.